# mvim open file as new tab in existing window from the command line

Tags: vim

I frequently use the command:

```
mvim -p file1 file2
```

to open multiple files in one window as tabs.
However it often happens that I subsequently want to open another file from the command line.
How do I tell mvim to open it as a new tab in the existing open window?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ mvim --remote-tab file3
```

MacVim first window is a Vim instance with `--servername` set to `VIM`. Each subsequent instance is named `VIM1`, `VIM2` and so on. The command above opens a new tab in the first instance by default, it's the equivalent of:

```
$ mvim --servername VIM --remote-tab .profile
```

If you want to open a tab in a specific instance, check its name at the top of the window. Assuming it's `VIM1`, do:

```
$ mvim --servername VIM1 --remote-tab .profile
```